# Serialport Readbyte() error; it's suddenly stop receiving data

Tags: c#

My code works fine but after a seconds I don't get any data from ReadByte(). And there is two expections under this function. How can I fix it ?
Here is the issue : https://i.hizliresim.com/7aPGXN.png

I have already tried ReadExisting() but it gives me immedieatly all of datas and I don't processs them.

```
private void bluetooth_port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int_verisi = bluetooth_port.ReadByte();

    textBox7.Text= int_verisi.ToString();
    byte_verisi = (byte) int_verisi;

    if ((byte_verisi & 0x0F) == 0)
    {
        //Mesafe Low Biti Çevirme
        byte_verisi_mesafe_lb = (byte) (byte_verisi >> 4);
        textBox1.Text = byte_verisi_mesafe_lb.ToString();
    }
    else if ((byte_verisi & 0x0F) == 0b00000001)
    {
        //Mesafe High Biti Çevirme
        byte_verisi_mesafe_hb = (byte) (byte_verisi & 0b11111110);
        textBox2.Text = byte_verisi_mesafe_hb.ToString();
    }
    else if ((byte_verisi & 0x0F) == 0b00000010)
    {
        //Servo Low Biti Çevirme
        byte_verisi_servo_lb = (byte)(byte_verisi >> 4);
        byte_verisi_servo_lb = (byte)(byte_verisi_servo_lb & 0b11011111);
        textBox4.Text = byte_verisi_servo_lb.ToString();
    }
    else if ((byte_verisi & 0x0F) == 0b00000100)
    {
        //Servo High Biti Çevirme
        byte_verisi_servo_hb = (byte)(byte_verisi & 0b11111011);
        textBox5.Text = byte_verisi_servo_hb.ToString();
    }

    mesafe_sensoru = (byte) (byte_verisi_mesafe_hb | byte_verisi_mesafe_lb);

    servo_aci = (byte)(byte_verisi_servo_hb | byte_verisi_servo_lb);

    textBox3.Text = mesafe_sensoru.ToString() + " cm";

    textBox6.Text = servo_aci.ToString() + " derece";
}
```

Comment: abi, the link is not working..

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't get any data from ReadByte()"? Does it return 0? or does it block and not return at all? Also, please show us the exceptions you get.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Zg8bNfW could you see this screenshot Andrew?

Comment: InvalidOperationExpection and System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutExpection those two expection shows when I move mouse to ReadByte() function. I didn't get any error when program is working but after a few seconds from start program, data shows zero.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I changed target framework to .NET framework 3.0.(from .NET framework 4.5.1).Still I don't understand why .NET framework 4.5.1 didn't work fine ?

Comment: You can't directly assign the Text property from your DataReceived event handler.  The event is raised on a threadpool thread, assigning Text is only legal on the UI thread.  You only get the InvalidOperationException when you run the program with a debugger.  Without one it can randomly deadlock the code.  This is a typical getting-started problem, using a TextBox to display every single received byte stops being practical very quickly.  Consider using Debug.WriteLine() instead.

Comment: I changed .Net Framework target and it works fine now, thanks for ideas...